# The WHERE IN clause using propel in symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony1, propel

How can I create the following query using propel ?

```
UPDATE tablename SET status = 1 WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$con = Propel::getConnection();

$selectCriteria = new Criteria();
$selectCriteria->add(TablenamePeer::ID, array(1,2,3,4), Criteria::IN);

$updateCriteria = new Criteria();
$updateCriteria->add(TablenamePeer::STATUS, 1);

BasePeer::doUpdate($selectCriteria, $updateCriteria, $con);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->add(ClassPeer::ID, array(1,2,3,4), Criteria::IN);
```

(I haven't used IN, so I'm only guessing that the 'value' argument should be an array). 
Criteria API documentation is at [1](http://www.tig12.net/downloads/apidocs/symfony/lib/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/vendor/propel/util/Criteria.class.html#det_constants_IN).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Didnt try it though.. Will try it in a while